# Break on default case in switch

Tags: programming-practices, switch-statement

I am a bit puzzled on whenever or not to include `break` after the last case, often `default`.

```
switch (type) {
    case 'product':

        // Do behavior

        break;
    default:

        // Do default behavior

        break; // Is it considered to be needed?
}
```

`break`s sole purpose is in my understanding to stop the code from running through the rest of the `switch`-case.

Is it then considered more logical to have a `break` last due to consistency or skip having it due to the `break` applying no functional use whatsoever? Both are logical in different ways in my opinion.

This could to a certain degree be compared with ending a `.php` file with `?>`. I never end with `?>` mostly due to the risk of outputting blank spaces, but one could argue that it would be the logical thing to end the file with.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

`break` isn't technically needed after the last alternative (which, mind you, doesn't have to be `default`: it is perfectly legal, and sometimes even useful to put the `default` branch first); whether your code falls through the end of the `switch` statement or `breaks` out at the end of its last branch has the same result.

However, I'd still end every branch, including the last one, with a `return` or `break` statement, for three reasons:

1. Refactorability. If all your branches end with `break` or `return`, you can reorder them without changing the meaning. This makes it less likely for such a reordering to introduce a regression.
2. Consistency, and Least Surprise. Consistency says your branches should end consistently, unless they are actually different in meaning. The Principle of Least Surprise dictates that similar things should look similar. Ending the last branch of a `switch` block exactly like the preceding ones fulfills both, which makes for easier reading and understanding. If you leave out the explicit `break`, the last branch will be optically different (which is especially important for quick scanning), and in order to see that it's really not different, the reader has to descend to the nitty-gritty level of reading individual statements.
3. Protecting yourself. If you make a habit of ending all your `switch` branches with a `break`, it will become automatic after a while, and you'll be less likely to accidentally forget it where it does matter. Training yourself to expect the `break` at the end of every branch also helps detecting missing `break` statements, which is great for debugging and troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for your insight in this! Will `break` last case aswell :)

Comment: In C#, `break` (or other control-flow statement that exits the `case`) *is* technically needed after the last alternative.

Comment: @dan04: yes, good point. C# is an exception here, and it's probably because the language designers knew about the problems with `switch` fall-through in existing languages and wanted to prevent them. The rules C# imposes pretty much match the recommendations from my answer.

Comment: What language are you talking about specifically? C? C++? C#? Java? PHP?

Comment: @svick: all of them, to varying degrees. C set the standard back in the days, and C++, Java, JavaScript and PHP use mostly the same rules. C# is a bit different in that it disallows fall-through, but otherwise, the same applies.

Comment: A good compiler would treat the final `break` as a NO-OP instead of generating a `jmp` to the next instruction, correct?

Answer (score 12):

Given the ambiguity that exists around the use of `switch-case` in most languages, when using it **I would suggest always using a `break` statement, except when it is explicitly and by design not wanted**.

Partly this is because is makes every `case` call look the same, which in my opinion would improve readability. But it also means if someone (even you) chooses to insert a `case` after the last one at a later stage, they don't need to concern themselves with checking the prior block, which could help reduce bugs when adding new code.

Comment: When I want one case to fall-through to the next (and it isn't the degenerate case of `case foo: case bar: ...`) I put an explicit comment in that I want the fall-through to happen. Makes it much clearer.

Comment: Yes like a simple comment `// no break` in place of `break;`

Comment: Or a `[[fallthrough]]` attribute in case of C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `break` necessary after the **last** case. I use the word "**last**"  (not **default** )because it is not necessary default case is the last case.

```
switch(x)
{
case 1:
//do stuff
break;

default:
//do default work
break;

case 3:
//do stuff

}
```

And we know, a `break`  is necessary between two consecutive `case`s. Sometimes, I use `if(a!=0)` in my code for more readability when others refer my code. I can choose to use `if(a)`, that would be a matter of my choice

Comment: For me that would mean a "always use break", just in case some programmer added a new `case` at the end of your `switch` without checking that the `break` did exist (it would be that programmer's fault, but still better be safe -if for any reason, because you could be that programmer in 6 months-)

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes,I agree, better safe than sorry, if you want to keep a safeguard for future errors, you must include one at the end.

Comment: With that argument in mind, you might aswell argue to always have `, ` in the end of arrays in case a new value is inserted. However that breaks some codes and generally looks ugly :)

Comment: @Robin Putting in a comma is different. If it is not there and someone adds a new value to an array then they will get a compile error. However there will be no compile error if the previous case statement is missing a break - so it would be possible for this to be missed and cause run-time errors.

Comment: @RobinCastlin Provided the language allowed you to put a `,` . Incase, `default` was designed to be the last case . Maybe the language would consider a `break` after it as an error. Assuming `break` was allowed as a differentiator ONLY between two cases.

Comment: Going off topic, but I prefer to put a comma after the last item in an array (for languages it is legal to do so). I prefer this because if I add a new element on the next line in the future, I'm only changing one line. This reduces the diff when looking at what changed. It's a very minor point, but anything I can do to minimise irrelevant "noise" in the diffs will help people see the important changes. So, of course, the newly added element gets a comma too - ready for the next addition!